# German visa and Blue Card

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, schengen, india

I have an offer from a German employer and the salary is 63K Euros. I am in India right now, and want to understand the correct visa process and ability to work in Germany.

During a conversation with an HR person, I was told to obtain a travel visa which is valid for 3 months. When this visa is granted, I'm supposed to travel to Germany and complete my joining formalities. After that, they will initiate a process for obtaining my Blue Card, which will allow me to remain in Germany and work.

I have not heard of this procedure before. I did some research on the Blue Card, and it looked alright, but I'm still concerned.

Here are the answers that I want to know.

1. What kind of visa would be raised when I have to travel from India to Germany? Is it the same as Schengen visa?
2. Is this visa process legitimate? I mean, the process of getting a visa to travel from India to Germany and then applying for a Bluecard.
3. How much money would be required to be shown in account to obtain the visa for travel from India to Germany?

Comment: I would never accept such offer. A serious company wouldn't bring you on a tourist Visa. There are 2 reasons they want to do in this way. First they want you to come as soon as possible, and start working for them. I suppose they want you to work in you "intermediate", tourist visa, right?

Secondly, they want you to come as a tourist, and take a look at you, evaluate if they really want to work with you, and they can trust you, then they go ahead and apply your visa. 

Anyways, I have a bad gut feeling from this deal Don't think twice, tell them you can only go with the proper way

Comment: @HelloWorldGuy http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/79958/41775

Comment: @HelloWorldGuy Actually nobody mentioned a *tourist* visa.

Comment: @HelloWorldGuy the company has no say in the matter. These immigration procedures are determined by German law.

Comment: You can also apply at the German embassy in your country of residence. In that case, you have to wait until you get a visa issued that allows you to travel to Germany. You will need to acquire the relevant documents up front. Those may include copies of things with apostilles. Make sure your university and the degree you have are listed in the EU database for the Blue Card. Once you get that temporary visa that already has § 19a (for blue card), you can come to Germany and start working immediately. You need to go to Auslaenderbehoerde where they will produce your physical card, which...

Comment: ... will take one month to make. With that, you can travel inside of Schengen. If you want to bring your family, do their visas at the same time as yours in your home country. What your company is suggesting is probably just them not knowing better. They will likely need to produce an invitation letter for you, and they might need to write a job description that the local job agency needs to verify and that will go to Auslaenderbehoerde before your initial visa is issued. (source: personal experience from company side) – also check http://www.make-it-in-germany.com/ for very useful advice.

Comment: @simbaque I don't think there is an EU database for the Blue Card, isn't it a German thing?

Comment: @Gala you're right. It's a German thing. This is it: http://anabin.kmk.org/anabin.html

Answer (score 2):

Getting a visa to enter the country and then applying for the actual residence permit is the regular procedure for (prospective) EU Blue card holders in Germany (and in many other EU countries). From the [ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/Infoservice/FAQ/ArbeitLebenDeutschland/02a-Blue%20Card%20EU.html?nn=350374):

> Die Blaue Karte EU wird in Deutschland ausschließlich von den Ausländerbehörden ausgestellt. Visumpflichtigen Drittstaatern wird für die Einreise in den Fällen, in denen ein Anspruch auf die Erteilung der Blauen Karte EU besteht, ein nationales Visum zur Beschäftigungseinreise von der jeweils zuständigen deutschen Auslandsvertretung erteilt. Das Visum wird nach der Einreise von der zuständigen Ausländerbehörde durch eine Blaue Karte EU ersetzt.

The only question is which specific visa you need. The three-month validity you mention in your question suggests they are thinking about a short-stay Schengen visa and I am not completely sure this would be the right visa.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it is the regular procedure. A Schengen visa cannot be issued for more than 3 months of uninterrupted stay, so this is fine as well. The point of this visa is that the person should get it to enter Germany and have enough time (3 months) to prepare the documents and apply for the residence permit (Blue Card).